# Version Angular 1.3 to 1.4

Tags: angularjs

I change my application version angular (1.3.0) to 1.4.0. Appear a problem in console, and i don't know what is the meaning of this.

If you can help me, thanks!!! [image: capture-description-image]

```
Uncaught Error: Invocation of form runtime.connect(null, ) doesn't match definition runtime.connect(optional string extensionId, optional object connectInfo)
at Object.normalizeArgumentsAndValidate (VM49397 extensions::schemaUtils:112)
at Object.<anonymous> (VM49392 extensions::binding:411)
at Object.<anonymous> (VM49391 extensions::runtime:129)
at Object.handleRequest (VM49392 extensions::binding:63)
at Object.<anonymous> (VM49392 extensions::binding:422)
at inject.js:27
```

Comment: The stack trace shows that the problem is coming from `inject.js` and not AngularJS. We need to see the relevant code, not just the stack trace.

Comment: See also https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-3-to-1-4